# Is there any wany to configure output directory for microbundle-crl to use React lazy loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, bundle, microbundle

I was using microbundle-crl to bundle my react application code,i was getting a huge single file as a output so tried to add Lazy loading so it will generate many small  chunks.but when i tried to compile i was getting the following error.

Error: You must set "output.dir" instead of "output.file" when generating multiple chunks.